# JDBC Re-read Data In ResultSet

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, resultset

I am retrieving a simple ResultSet from my SQL Server database using the Microsoft JDBC Driver (mssqlserver.jar).  I think it is the MSSQL2000 Driver which is downloaded from [Microsoft JDBC][1]

I am wanting to call the getter methods more than once to access the values but when you do the following exception is thrown:

> `java.sql.SQLException`: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]`ResultSet` can not re-read row data for column 1.

Question is, I am retrieving data into a ResultSet.  From the ResultSet, I am accessing the data in my code before passing the ResultSet on to elsewhere in code to be reused.

Code is similar to as follows:

```
// build query string
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM SomeWhere";

// get the data
Statement statement = sourceConnection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectQuery);

while( rs.next() ) {

    // do my own internal processing 
    doSomethingWithRs(rs);

    // now do something with the record set outside - in subclass
    afterRowCopied(rs);
}

// ...

private void doSomethingWithRs(ResultSet rs) {
    // access data   
    for( int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
        Object o = rs.getObject(i);
        // do something with o...
    }

}
```

**Edit**

I am using Java 1.6 for this.

**end Edit**

Any thoughts?
All I can think of doing is repackaging the data with the ResultSetMetaData into a custom class.

Not really found too much posts on this issue.  Microsoft website not any help at all.

Comment: Is it possible for you change the driver. Can you use jtds instead http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Comment: sandeepnair85, something to look into for future - definitely.  But cant change just yet as everything is pretty much database orientated, it would result in a lot of testing as the management would not be 100% confident of replacing. Would have +1'd for your answer, but you put must have deleted before putting this comment on

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be by design, according to ["ResultSet Can Not Re-Read Row Data"' Error When Reading Data from a JDBC ResultSet Object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824106/en-gb):

> This error occurs with ResultSet objects that contain a BLOB column (for example, text, ntext, or image data types). The driver cannot return a BLOB column out of order because it does not cache all the content of BLOB data types because of size limitations.
>
> For any row in the ResultSet, you can read any column from left to right, and each column should be read only one time. If you try to read columns out of order, or if you re-read a column from the ResultSet, you may receive the error message that the "Symptoms" section describes.
>
> **This behavior is by design**.

You either need to use a different JDBC driver, or refactor your code to only read those BLOB columns once for any given row.  This a good idea anyway, since re-reading BLOBs can be a performance killer.

Comment: skaffman, thats exactly what I am looking at - read the row once next() is called.  Might be overkill, but creating a new class that implements ResultSet first and see how far I get.  There are 100s of methods to override though!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading the data once and copying to an Object array and passing it to methods instead of passing the resultset.  That can be more clean code also.

Comment: prajeesh, I needed the meta data for the result set where I manipulate it outisde of the super class so an Object array would not suffice in this instance.

Comment: Well, if you need the metadata, you can pass the resultset also but not read from it again and again. Create a `List<Object[]>`, read the values into this once and call the methods with this additional parameter. I dont know how much it will suit, but this can atleast get things going with minimal overhead.

Answer (score 1):

The long winded nightmare approach (which does work) but I have lazily just implemented most of the getters.

**Edit**

As I mentioned, I am using JDK 1.6.  However, when compiled against the JDK 1.7 a compilation error is encountered:

```
error: ReadOnlyResultSet is not abstract and does not override abstract method <T>getObject(String,Class<T>) in ResultSet
```

**end Edit**

To do this create a class that implements the ResultSet (Let Netbeans add the default method implementation stubs).  Then in the constructor, store a reference to the initial ResultSet.  In next(), cache the values in an array.  Proabably have to do the same for previous() and other set cursor methods.  So the class will look like:

```
public class ReadOnlyResultSet
    implements ResultSet {
    /**
     * The original data source.
     */
    private ResultSet source;
    /**
     * Cached values for the current row.
     */
    private Object[] values;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of <code>ReadOnlyResultSet</code>.
     */
    public ReadOnlyResultSet(ResultSet source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean next() throws SQLException {
        // NOTE:  values[0] will always be null as JDBC is 1 based arrays
        boolean next = source.next();
        if( next ) {
            values = new Object[source.getMetaData().getColumnCount() + 1];
                for(int i = 1; i < source.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++ ) {
                    values[i] = source.getObject(i);
                }
            } else {
                // no current row
                values = new Object[] { };
            }

            return next;
        }

        // implement all of the not getter/setter methods
        @Override
        public void close() throws SQLException {
            source.close();
        }

        // implement getters I am interested in
        @Override
        public String getString(int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
            return (String) values[columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public String getString(String columnLabel) throws SQLException {
            return (String) values[findColumn(columnLabel)];
        }

        // just too much implementation but hopefully you get the drift
```

}